# What do I use now that BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

How do I fix the deprecation warning in this code? Alternatively, are there any other options for doing this?
[image]

```
   val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {}
```

Comment: which java version you are using?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()), they now recommend this:

```
val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
bluetoothManager.getAdapter()
```

The reason seems to be that `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` ignores Context, while more complex apps might need to explicitly reference the correct Context and use Context.createAttributionContext.

Not a good reason to deprecate it in my opinion, as I can't think of a realistic/frequent usecase where the BluetoothAdapter needs to be based on a tagged Context. They should have just left both options (Context based and default) in without deprecation.

Answer (score 4):

```
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) YourContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

Comment: I used your code but wasn't working.... then I added the imports and it worked fine... I just meged the lines into one.

imports: android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager, import android.content.Context; 

BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = ((BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();